# pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen() is getting incorrect coordinates when looking for the Spotify pause button

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

Trying to locate the Spotify pause button on my screen using `pyautogui` just to develop my python knowledge. I run the script below and a screenshot of the pause button is saved, but the mouse moves to the bottom right of the screen, miles away from where the button is.

```
import pyautogui

input("Move to target button") #move mouse to pause button
target = pyautogui.position()
local = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("spotify.png", confidence=0.9, grayscale=False)#spotify.png is a screenshot of the pause button

pyautogui.moveTo(local)
print(f"Found: {local}")
print(f"Target: {target}")

#sloppy but wanted to ensure the xy coordinates were correct
x = list(local) 
x.append(100)
x.append(100)
im = pyautogui.screenshot('test.png', region=x)
```

Example output:

```
Move to target button
Found: Point(x=1487, y=780)
Target: Point(x=746, y=392)
```

Screensize is `1440 x 900`

There is no matching image at the coordinates the mouse is directed to, but from the screenshots it seems one has been found? How do I fix this so my mouse goes to the pause button, not the bottom far right of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

import pyautogui
import time

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1) #prevents lag and waits for new image
    spotify = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('spotify.PNG', confidence=.7,grayscale=False) #image location
    if spotify: #if the image is found
        print('found image clicking...')
        pyautogui.click(spotify)
```

Comment: Same problem, mouse goes somewhere random and clicks

Comment: Up the confidence